# Getting Weird Outputs When Iterating Through Array C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have an array of `char` pointers as such `char *arrayHolder[20]`.  When I try to loop through the array I get unexpected outputs if the user inputs items on the second input

Example:

```
input> 1 2 3 
1
2
3
input>2 3 4 
3
3 
3

1
```

Loop causing Errors:

```
for(i = 0; arrayHolder[i] != NULL; ++i) { 
    printf("%c\n", arrayHolder[i]);
```

Code for Token input:

```
char* token; 
char buffer [100];
char input[25000];
int i;
char *tokenHolder[300];
int pos = 0; 

while(1) {
    printf("repl> ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    while(token != NULL) {
        tokenHolder[pos] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        pos++;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code where you are filling array?

Comment: The infinite while loop is in the scope of the for loop. Just fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `pos = 0` before second `while` loop.

```
pos = 0; //<-- This.
while(token != NULL)
{    
   tokenHolder[pos] = token;
   token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   pos++;
}
```

Edit after new problem faced by OP:

1. `Break` first `while` loop, it is infinite now. for test, I broke it after 3 cycles.
2. use of `char* name[300]` was not correct, I have corrected that.
3. Use `int row` to make sure all data entered is filled in array correctly.
4. `printf()` changed to `%s` from `%c` as printing done for `char*` and not for `char`

> ```
> int main()
> {
>   char* token; 
>   char buffer [100];
>   int i;
>   char *tokenHolder[300];
>   int pos = 0; 
>   int row = 0;
>
>   while(1)
>   {       
>       printf("repl> ");
>       fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
>       token = strtok(buffer, " ");
>
>       pos = 0;
>       while(token != NULL){
>
>           (tokenHolder + row)[pos] = token;
>           token = strtok(NULL, " ");
>           pos++;
>       }
>       (tokenHolder + row)[pos] = '\0';
>
>       for(i =0; (tokenHolder + row)[i] != NULL; ++i){ 
>           printf("%s\n", (tokenHolder + row)[i]); 
>       }
>       row++;
>       if(row > 2) // Breaking of row exceeds 10. You can enter your suitable condition.
>           break;
>   }
>
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Edited, Now, I get a Seg Fault when trying to output tokenHolder[i], and when I try tokenHolder[i][i] I get the behavior described in the initial description. I tested printf("%s\n", tokenHolder[2]) to see if my values were being inputted correctly and they were.

Comment: @user2757849 you need tokenHolder as char *tokenHolder[300]; or char tokenHolder[300];? one is Array of pointer holding each element 300 chars and other is just one array with 300 chars?

Comment: @user2757849 Edited.. check now.

Comment: Could explain how the functionality of the row works?

Comment: I used a array of pointer because if I didn't the compiler gave me this warning, warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default] token = strtok(buffer, " "); 
I tested using char token and char tokenHolder[200] and went I went to print the first initial position I got no output and a ton of warnings.

Comment: @user2757849 the code given did not work for you? what specific problem? row is used to accommodate two dimension array.